# How to solve for $x$ in $\frac{e^x}{e^x + 2} = 0.9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve for $x$ in $\frac{e^x}{e^x + 2} = 0.9$ ?

I took log on both sides and arrived to 
$$x - \log(e^x + 2) = \log0.9$$

and I am not sure how to proceed...

I tried step by step solution in Wolfram Alpha, but I do not understand how they got the following step...
[image]

Can someone help me to solve for $x$ and explain this transformation that W.A. gave me

Comment: Don't let the $e^x$ rattle you.  Replace $e^x$ with $m$ and solve $\frac m{m+2} = .9$  ($m = .9(m+2)=.9m +1.8;.1*m = 1.8; m =e^x = 18$.)  Once you solve $e^x = m$ take the natural log and get $x = \ln m$.  (So $m=e^x = 18$ so $x = \ln m = \ln 18$)

Comment: "I tried step by step solution in Wolfram Alpha"  Wolfram Alpha is a brainless computer algorithm.  It is not a human being. $\frac {e^x}{e^x + 2} = \frac {e^x + 2 - 2}{e^x+2} = 1 - \frac 2{e^x +2}$.  Let $y=\frac 1{e^x+2}$ so $1-2y =.9; y=.05$ so $\frac 1y = 20$.  So $e^x+2 = 20$ so $e^x = 18$.  So $x = \ln 18$.  It make sense to program a computer to do this but for you or me.... what a lot of wasted steps and effort.

Comment: So how would you tell an automaton how to solve $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=h(x)$? Well, you'd tell a human being to look at $f(x) = h(x)g(x)$ and see if it looks solvable and if it doesn't try something else.  Well, you tell an automaton to reduces $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(x)=kg(x) + g'(x)}{g(x)} = k + \frac {g'(x)}{g(x)}=h(x)$ and keep repeating until you get something simple.  That *will* eventually fall to bits but... it's a lot of *human* work to get to that stage and instead there is very likely something a lot simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, $y$ is just a variable introduced for simplification purposes. Try approaching it this way.
$$ \frac{e^x}{e^x+2}=0.9$$
$$ e^x=0.9(e^x+2)$$
$$ e^x=0.9e^x+1.8$$
$$ (1-0.9)e^x=1.8$$
$$ 0.1e^x=1.8$$
$$ e^x=18$$
$$ x=\log 18.$$

Comment: yeah that's really easy way of doing it. how I did not see it lol

Comment: Happens to the best of us :-)

Answer (score 4):

$$1-\frac{2}{e^x+2}=\frac{1(e^x+2)-2}{e^x+2}=\frac{e^x}{e^x+2}$$
and so
$$\frac{e^x}{e^x+2}=0.9$$
$$\implies 1-\frac{2}{e^x+2}=0.9$$
$$\implies \frac{2}{e^x+2}=1-0.9=0.1$$
$$\implies e^x+2=\frac{2}{0.1}=20$$
$$\implies e^x=18$$
$$\implies x=\ln(18)$$

Answer (score 2):

Try comparing reciprocals of both sides:
$$\frac{e^x+2}{e^2} = \frac {10}9$$
leads to
$$1+\frac 2{e^x}=\frac{10}9$$
hence
$$\frac 2{e^x}=1/9$$
and
$$2\cdot 9=e^x$$
so
$$x=\ln{18}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{e^x}{e^x+2} = \frac{e^x + 2}{e^x+2} - \frac{2}{e^x+2} = 1 - \frac{2}{e^x+2}.$$
After setting this equal to $0.9$, it should be easier to solve for $x$ now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mention of the Moebius transformation here. If we have quantities $u,v,$ with
$$  \frac{Au + B}{C u + D} = v,   $$ and $AD - BC \neq 0,$ then
$$ u = \frac{ \; Dv - B}{ \; \; -C v + A} $$
In your case $u = e^x, v = 0.9, A=1, B=0, C=1,D=2.$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
D & -B \\
-C & A \\
\end{array}
\right) = \; \;  (AD-BC) \;
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$